# how to bind telerik tree view to multple level stored procedures

Tags: treeview, telerik

I currently have a 2 level tree view that displays departments and then assets within those departments. To do this I am using a sql stored procedure to prepare the data. See the attatched file to see the output of this stored procedure. 
[image]

I am wondering how to go about adding in another level. IE I want to have a tree view that started with SITE's that have Departments which have Assets. IE I want to add a grand parent to the tree view.

What would the sql look like for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to modify the parentId values for the current root records and leave the SITE record solely with NULL parentId while the present six roots should have parent id which points to the SITE grand parent.